# Web Application Proxy appending authtoken to Url

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, proxy, windows-authentication, windows-server-2012-r2

I am using non claims aware application in Web Application Proxy.
Server: Windows Server 2016
ADFS: v3.0 - Windows Server 2012 R2

But whenever I request the application URL, a query string parameter 'authtoken' is appending after the successful authentication.

[image]

How can I remove this token?